# Comparing WTForms field label to string always returns False

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

If a field label is "Log-in" I don't want to show the label just the input itself.  But comparing the `field.label` in the macro to "Log-in" is always false because the `<p>hello</p>` is never rendered.  How can I compare the labels to a string?

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  {%if field.label == "Log-in" %}
    <p>hello</p>
  {%else%}
    {{ field.label }} {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {%endif%}
{% endmacro %}

<div id = "SignUpForm">
    <form action = "" method = "post" name = "SignUpForm">
        <p>{{render_field(form.username)}}</p>
        <p>{{render_field(form.first_name)}}</p>
        <p>{{render_field(form.last_name)}}</p>
        <p>{{render_field(form.password)}}</p>
        <p>{{render_field(form.password2)}}</p>
        <p>{{form.submit}}</p>
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need compare to `field.label.text`.  The `.text` part is missing.  The label object itself is not a string.